# How to display Airport Code from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code almost working, but can't get the airport code to be populated auto display.
I would like to auto display the option of the Airport code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Countries
  var country_arr = new Array("Select Country", "AUSTRALIA", "EUROPE", "SINGAPORE", "USA");

  $.each(country_arr, function(i, item) {
    $('#country').append($('<option>', {
      value: i,
      text: item,
    }, '</option>'));
  });

  // States
  var state = new Array();
  state[0] = "Select State";
  state[1] = "Select State|QUEENSLAND|VICTORIA|NEW-SOUTH-WALES";
  state[2] = "Select State|NETHERLANDS";

  // Cities
  var city = new Array();
  city['QUEENSLAND'] = "BRISBANE";
  city['VICTORIA'] = "MELBOURNE";
  city['NEW-SOUTH-WALES'] = "SYDNEY";
  city['NETHERLANDS'] = "AMSTERDAM";


  // AIRPORT CODE
  var code = new Array();
  code['BRISBANE'] = "BNE1";
  code['MELBOURNE'] = "MEL1";
  code['SYDNEY'] = "SYD1";
  code['AMSTERDAM'] = "AMS1";

  $('#country').change(function() {
    var c = $(this).val();
    var state_arr = state[c].split("|");
    $('#state').empty();
    $('#city').empty();
    $('#code').empty();
    if (c == 0) {
      $('#state').append($('<option>', {
        value: '0',
        text: 'Select State',
      }, '</option>'));
    } else {
      $.each(state_arr, function(i, item_state) {
        $('#state').append($('<option>', {
          value: item_state,
          text: item_state,
        }, '</option>'));
      });
    }
    $('#city').append($('<option>', {
      value: '0',
      text: 'Select city',
    }, '</option>'));
  });

  $('#state').change(function() {
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s == 'Select State') {
      $('#city').empty();
      $('#city').append($('<option>', {
        value: '0',
        text: 'Select city',
      }, '</option>'));
    }
    var city_arr = city[s].split("|");
    $('#city').empty();

    $.each(city_arr, function(j, item_city) {
      $('#city').append($('<option>', {
        value: item_city,
        text: item_city,
      }, '</option>'));
    });
  });

  $('#code').change(function() {
    var s = $(this).val();
    if (s == 'Select City') {
      $('#code').empty();
      $("div").text(s);
    }
    var code_arr = $(this).val();
    $('#code').empty();

    $.each(code_arr, function(j, item_code) {
      $("div").text(code_arr);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country"></select> <br>
<select name="state" id="state"></select> <br>
<select name="city" id="city"></select>
<input name="code" id="code" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="1" type="text" maxlength="2" required>
<label for="code">Airport Code</label>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0c1hmq7/18)

Comment: Please have a look you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/sanat/kor7m3d8/

Comment: thanks, I was missing this.. $("#code").val(code[item_city]); thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look I hope it's useful.
You missed this line inside the city each function.

```
$("#code").val(code[item_city]);
```

[URL](http://jsfiddle.net/sanat/kor7m3d8)

Comment: hi @sanat, what if there are multiple city within states, and which needs to correspond with the correct Airport code, with the current solution it doesn't work, It only works with the first available

Comment: @miu Hi if you have multiple cities then you need to find airport code on city change not state change.

Comment: @miu Please check `http://jsfiddle.net/sanat/0czm7sng/` I can do for `EUROPE` you can do like this.

Comment: Hello Sanat, It only works with Europe, not other city selected... can u please check..

Comment: @miu Yes I can do only for `EUROPE` for example, you can do as same as `EUROPE`  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to store first, city codes in a jQuery/Javascript readable file format like JSON.
After that, you can parse JSON file in your jQuery Code. And now codes automatically fetched from JSON file when you select city.

[Know About JSON Format And How to Fetch It](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-json)

Comment: Hello, Once the value show in the text, How to extract the string, store into DB. I'm using Django..